# PHP: How to rewrite non-English URL to index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I use this code in .htaccess to rewrite all page to index.php page:

```
RewriteRule ^([][\w\s$:!()'"-]+)/?$ ?file=$1 [L]
```

It worked perfectly with English URL. However, it show 404 Error when access non-English URL.

For example: mywebsite.com/%EA%B3%A0%EC%B9%B4%EC%A7%80%EB%85%B8
 or mywebsite.com/고카지노

So, how to rewrite them ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Your rule is very obviously not matching `%` or `\x80-\xFF` bytes. Also note that just because you constrain the virtual input paths doesn't by itself prevent direct script invocations like `index.php?file=../../etc/passwd` (which is what the `file=` param implies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't restrict your rule. Use it like this:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```